# Debugger does not break the code when exceptions are thrown

Tags: c#, winforms

When debugging my `Winform` program, I recently found that instead of breaking in the source code lines that do bad, the program will pop up a dialog showing error message, something like below:

[image]

This is not good for me as I didn't know where in the code that caused this failure, do you know why my `Visual Studio` debugger behaves like this and how can I alter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are running your application in `Non-Debug` mode it will not break your code ,it just displays the error message in `MessageBox`

if you want to throw exception and point to your code exactly where exception raised you need to Run you program in `Debug` mode.

**EDIT:** if you are already in Debug mode try this:

**Step 1:** Goto `Debug` menu in VS IDE
**Step 2:** Select `Exceptions`
**Step 3:** now You need to check the `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` option in `Exceptions` dialog.

[image]

Comment: I was in `Debug` mode :(

Comment: Note that if you have "Just my Code" enabled in the debugger options the screen will [look slightly different](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rk3ql.png), but you still follow the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you catch exceptions in your program and show a message box in that case. Probably with a blanket `catch (Exception e)`. You can make the debugger to break into any exception thrown, even if caught under Debug > Exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could show the `StackTrace` instead of the `Message`, which contains a drill down to the call that caused the exception.

You could show your message like this:

```
try
{
    // some code that throws an exception
}
catch()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendFormat("Message: {0}", e.Message);
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.AppendLine();
    sb.AppendFormat("StackTrace: {0}", e.StackTrace);
    MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "Error");
}
```